# Is there a way to look at the back-end processing of PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, anomaly-detection

I am new to StackOverflow so please do correct me if I need to provide any more information.

I am trying to integrate an anomaly detection into the PostgreSQL database system by plugging into its backend.

I would like to know if there is any place where I can find extensive back-end coding or integration examples. I am looking at papers regarding this topic and, so far, I have found a few which talk about the methods that the queries are classified and used for anomaly detection.

If you do know about any websites which might help me, please do provide links to the sites.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you asking about native data structures used for the engine, or are you interested in memory limit threshold type of things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What kind of "anomalies" are you talking about?

Comment: I am looking for information regarding how to access the queries using the log history. I have found that Query trees seem to be one place to look for the data I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for "hooks" in the PostgreSQL source tree. Studying the source of the `auto_explain` and `pg_stat_statements` contrib modules, which track query execution, will show you the way.

The source is its own book: it is well-documented and interspersed with README files that explain the design.